# SQL Server Determine Physical Size of Table Columns

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to find out how big the data is in KB or MB for individual columns in a table?  I have a script which tells me the physical size of each table, but I would like to know how much of that is taken up by certain columns in the database, especially when I have XML stored in a column.

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Not to my knowledge, sorry. Rarely wanted. For others to answer that - what version of SQL Server are you using - may be relevant here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to use the datalength function, something like

```
select sum(datalength(yourfield))
from yourtable
```

This will summate the datalengths of all the entries of that field in the table - it will not account for overheads such as variable length field pointers, space in the nullability bitmap etc.

Comment: It should be noticed this returns the length in bytes - I found this useful for my purposes.

select concat(sum(datalength(yourfield)) / 1024, ' kb')
from yourtable

Answer (score 9):

This will return all columns in a specific database with their data size and can easily be updated to only return the numbers for a specific table or column.

```
USE [YourDatabase]
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
CREATE TABLE #temp (tablename varchar(max), columnname varchar(max), sizeinkb float)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD 
FOR SELECT table_name, column_name, table_schema FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Open My_Cursor 
DECLARE @table varchar(max), @column varchar(max), @schema varchar(max)
Fetch NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @table, @column, @schema
While (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) = 'INSERT #temp SELECT ''' + @schema + '.' + @table + ''', ''' + @column + ''', sum(isnull(datalength([' + @column + ']), 0)) / 1024.0 FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] (NOLOCK)'
    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @table, @column, @schema
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
GO

SELECT *, sizeinkb / 1024.0 sizeinmb FROM #temp ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: I had an 'INT' overflow : 'Msg 8115, Level 16, Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int'. And here is the modification I did :     `DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) = 'INSERT #temp SELECT ''' + @schema + '.' + @table + ''', ''' + @column + ''', sum(CAST(isnull(datalength([' + @column + ']), 0) as bigint)) / 1024.0 FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] (NOLOCK)'`. Inspired from 'https://database.guide/fix-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-int-in-sql-server/'

Answer (score 6):

For view size of **"all columns a table"**, you can first generate fields of your table with:

```
SELECT 'SUM(DATALENGTH('+Column_name+')) / (1024*1024) as '+Column_name+'_MB,'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '--TABLE_NAME--'
```

and next, run this query:

```
SELECT
    /*result previous query (with remove last comma)*/
FROM --TABLE_NAME--
```

Comment: Just what I was searching for. Thanks!

A version that can overflow int max:

SELECT 'SUM(Cast(DATALENGTH('+Column_name+') as bigint)) / (1024*1024) as '+Column_name+'_MB,'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'name here'

Answer (score 2):

Select SUM(DATALENGTH(columnsA)) / 1024.0 AS KB